# Why is this series of house prices being thrown into one bin with plt.hist?

Tags: python, visualization

I have a series of houseprices that looks like this:

```
0    410000 
1    610000 
2    579950 
3    559950 
4    404950 
Name: price, dtype: int64
```

And using `plt.hist(df.price)` I get the below histogram, which is not useful. What is causing this? Am I missing something here? I want a range of prices to be binned together and their frequencies to be plotted.

[image]

Comment: Could it be that you have a small group of outliers way at 1e8 while most observations fall in 1e7 range? Histogram uses linearly-spaced bins, so it could result in the image above. Can you `plt.hist()` a small subsample of data?

Comment: @K3---rnc Yes, that's definitely it. I can't believe I didn't think about that! The max is 9.825000e+07 where as the means is 2.949922e+05. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Can't reproduce:

```
>>> housing = pd.DataFrame([410000, 610000, 579950, 559950, 404950],
                           columns=['price'], dtype=int)
>>> housing.price
0    410000
1    610000
2    579950
3    559950
4    404950
Name: price, dtype: int64

>>> plt.hist(housing.price)
```

[image]

#### Resolution

**You have an outlier at 1e8 while most observations fall into 1e7 range.**

Comment: I used matplotlib first then tried seaborn but both were the same. In reality my dataset is a lot bigger and has 981878, but that shouldn't change much right?

Comment: Oh, so your plot above is not of those five specified values? See my comment above.